# What is the best way to calculate the mean of the values of a pandas dataframe with np.nan in it?

Tags: python, dataframe, nan, mean

I'm trying to calculate the mean of the values (all of them numeric, not like in the 'How to calculate the mean of a pandas DataFrame with NaN values' question) of a pandas dataframe containing a lot of np.nan in it.

I've came with this code, that works quite well by the way :

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame ([[0,10,np.nan,220],\
[1,np.nan,21,221],[2,12,22,np.nan],[np.nan,13,np.nan,np.nan]])

print(my_df.values.flatten()[~np.isnan(my_df.values.flatten())].mean())
```

However, I found that this line of code gives the same result, which I don't understand why :

```
print(my_df.values[~np.isnan(my_df.values)].mean())
```

Is this really the same, and can I use it safely ?
I mean, `my_df.values[~np.isnan(my_df.values)` is still an array that is not flat and so what happened to the `np.nan` in it ?

Any improvement is welcome if you see a more efficient and pythonic way to do that.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this really the same, and can I use it safely ?

Yes, since numpy here masks away the NaNs, and it will then calculate the mean over that array. But you make it overcomplicated here.

You can use numpy's [**`nanmean(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) here:

```
>>> np.nanmean(my_df)
52.2
```

The NaN values are thus not take into account (not in the sum nor in the count of the mean). I think this is probably more declarative than calculating the mean with masking, since the above says *what* you are doing, and not that much *how* you are doing that.

In case you want to count the NaNs, we can replace these with `0` like [@abdullah.cu says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239459/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-the-mean-of-the-values-of-a-pandas-dataframe-w/57239485?noredirect=1#comment100980642_57239485), like:

```
>>> my_df.fillna(0).values.mean()
32.625
```

Comment: If taking the frequency of `nan`s into account is needed,  one could replace `nan`s with zeros (i.e. `my_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`) then calculate the mean as `my_df.mean()`.

Comment: @abdullah.cu: but that would mean that you count the `nan`s as well. `nanmean` usually aims to exclude these from the mean (so `[1,nan,2]` yields `1.5`, not `1`).

Comment: Yeah you are right. I am pointing out to it just in case it is needed.

Comment: Thank you ! So much more compact and elegant.